# Error: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject even by using Dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, xaml

The following is part of my `View` in which I have bound an Image to a property in my `ViewModel`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

My `ViewModel` is this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    Action _makeScannerAlwaysOnAction;
    private BitmapImage _image;


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        AddNewPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenFrmAddNewPerson);
        FingerPrintScannerDevice.FingerPrintScanner.Init();
        MakeScannerAlwaysOn(null);
    }

    private void MakeScannerAlwaysOn(object obj)
    {
        _makeScannerAlwaysOnAction = MakeScannerOn;
        _makeScannerAlwaysOnAction.BeginInvoke(Callback, null);
    }

    private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        FingerPrintScannerDevice.FingerPrintScanner.UnInit();
        var objFingerPrintVerifier = new FingerPrintVerifier();
        objFingerPrintVerifier.StartVerifingProcess();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Position = 0;
        objFingerPrintVerifier.MatchPerson.Picture.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        var bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => Image = bi);
        //Image = bi;

        _makeScannerAlwaysOnAction.BeginInvoke(Callback, null);
    }

    private void MakeScannerOn()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (FingerPrintScannerDevice.FingerPrintScanner.ScannerManager.Scanners[0].IsFingerOn)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**My Problem:**
The problem is when I want to bind the Image it gives me the error

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

I have googled a lot and I have seen the post in SO but neither of them worked for me.

any kind of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: try `bi.Freeze()` after you create it and before you update `Image`

Comment: oh thanks. it worked like a magic. what does it do? I thought it might be a threading problem. try post the answer to be accepted

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx should give you the info about Freezing you require.

Comment: What we can't see, is who is creating the image and how is the property being set.  Here's my thoughts, you should spin off a task like this.  Task.Run(( //do image stuff here  )=>);  When the task completes it will automatically join the GUI thread if it was spun off there.  Plus it will be about 5 times faster too.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`BitmapImage` is `DependencyObject` so it does matter on which thread it has been created because you cannot access `DependencyProperty` of an object created on another thread unless it's a [`Freezable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable(v=vs.110).aspx) object and you can [`Freeze`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735(v=vs.110).aspx) it.

> Makes the current object unmodifiable and sets its IsFrozen property to true.

What you need to do is call `Freeze` before you update `Image`:

```
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
bi.Freeze();

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => Image = bi);
```

as pointed out by @AwkwardCoder here is [Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: very useful for Video streaming from ImageSource creating drivers, especially since running acquisition on the UI's synchronization context is very costly and causes UI to freeze. +1 mate!

Comment: What if I don't want to update an `Image` where the `Freeze` method is availabel but for example a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>`? The `Freeze` method is not available in this type...

Answer (score 0):

While `bi.Freeze();` worked for me in one case, I've seen no difference from adding/removing

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => Image = bi);
```

The second time I used `DataTemplate` in xaml and all the same classes as in the first case, but I kept getting the same Error.

This was a thing that helped:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Image = bi);
```

Maybe accepted answer can be improved because Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher don't actually give you UI thread.