# Can I Create or Fill ViewModels and ObservableCollection in a Background Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a MVVM (C#/WPF) application and want to create and fill my ViewModels (with INotifyPropertyChange) and ObservableCollections in an Background Thread.

If I do so I get an Exception: "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

I know how to use the Dispatcher to move Actions in the UI-Thread. But it is not clear to me what has to move to the UI-Thread. I have the following 5 cases.

1. `var vm = new ViewModel(); // implements INotifyPropertyChange`
2. `vm.Name = "name"; // Fires PropertyChange`
3. `var oc = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();`
4. `oc.Add(vm);`
5. `var oc2 = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(list); // while list is List of ViewModel`

Comment: "it is not clear to me what has to move to the UI-Thread": Start with anything that throws an exception otherwise.

Comment: I think you can do this if you [freeze](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx) the objects before you modify it on the background thread.  [Check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26361859/1118082)

Comment: "I have the following 5 cases" - what does that mean.  Where is the code that using a background thread and what line is throwing the error?

Comment: The Exception isn't thrown by one of these lines directly. It's thrown by the "consuming code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `ObservableCollection<T>.Add()` on a non-`Dispatcher` thread.

You can create an `ObservableCollection<T>` on a non-`Dispatcher` thread.

It should not matter what thread you create your `ViewModel` objects on as long as you don't have any `Dispatcher`-only calls in the constructor.

**Update from comment about PropertyChanged events:**

You need to raise `PropertyChanged` events on the `Dispatcher` thread in order for them to be processed. I've found it useful for those situations to just wrap the raising of the event in a `Dispatcher.Invoke()` call.

**Update for case-specific answers**

- Case 1: Can be on any thread as long as no `Dispatcher`-specific calls in the constructor.
- Case 2: Should be raised on `Dispatcher` if you want the event to be processed by any bound Controls.
- Case 3: Can be on any thread.
- Case 4: Must be on `Dispatcher`.
- Case 5: Can be on any thread.

Comment: So - Case 1 (with an empty constructor) could run in a non-dispatcher thread and case 2 has to run in a dispatcher thread? And PropertyChange() a dispatcher only call?