# WPF Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this has been asked many times, but I tried all solutions I found and no one works for me.

I have the following code:

```
    public async void setFile(QuickBrowseFile file) {
        try {
            LoggingDatabaseService db = new LoggingDatabaseService();
            LoggingData data = await db.getLoggingData(file.Id);
            db.close();
            if (data != null) {
                List<LoggingModel> loggingData = data.RowData;
                int numRows = loggingData.Count;

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(delegate {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                        LoggingModel m = loggingData[i];
                        treeView.Items.Add(m);//!!!!!!!!!!!!exception here
                    }
                }));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
```

I tried a different solution, but problem is that I have a gif image that shows some frames using the solution from [How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf).

Using the code below doesn't throw any exception, but block the gif image while loading..

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

    LoggingDatabaseService db = new LoggingDatabaseService();
    //Console.WriteLine(file.Id);
    LoggingData data = db.getLoggingData(file.Id);
    db.close();
    if (data != null) {
        List<LoggingModel> loggingData = data.RowData;
        int numRows = loggingData.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            treeView.Items.Add(loggingData[i]);
        }
    }
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting on your 1st block of code?

Comment: Its:

Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

Comment: You can try passing the synchronization context to your `Task.Factory.StartNew` like `var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);`. Tasks are created on background threads, see if this helps.

Comment: Why do you want to move the `treeView.Items.Add(m)` to a separate worker? This shouldn't be the slow part of your code, unless your design is flawed.

Comment: Can you modify your code to produce this behavior without accessing external data (verifyable example)?

Comment: The slow part is db.getLoggingData(file.Id) - it takes some time to get data from the database. @Ephraim I tried this solution, but I can't use await db.getLoggingData(file.Id) because of the error that I should use async.. I'm new to WPF and C#, so maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Could it be that you don't create `treeView` in the dispatcher thread?

Comment: treeView is added using XAML, so its:
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Width="180"

Comment: If the slow part is `db.getLoggingData(file.Id)`, then you should be concerned about moving having this action out of the UI thread context. What is the code behind `getLoggingData`?

Comment: `getLoggingData` reads data from the database. The first version loads data in a different thread, non UI but when adding items it fails with the exception in the title. Second version doesn't throw any exceptions, but blocks UI thread.

Comment: What is the code behind `getLoggingData`? What are the exact return types? Can't you just run-await a task that calls the code before `if (data != null)` and process the rest without any special thread? Where is `setFile` called from? `setFile` doesn't look like an event handler, so it shouldn't be `async void`...

Comment: `setFile` is called from the constructor of the parent window. `getLoggingData` returns an object with some data from DB. I think the first version provided does what you suggest - waits for a task and then create the UI, but it fails with the error in the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject even by using Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361020/error-must-create-dependencysource-on-same-thread-as-the-dependencyobject-even)